# my wifi manager has huge issues, fix? alternatives?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, connection

The wifi manager in my ubuntu seems to have some problems.

1. Quite often when the connection drops I have to wait 10 minutes to have it back, or I even have to reboot (not always with improvements);
2. Where my mobile phone connects easily the pc doesn't even see the connection
3. Sometimes connects without showing it in the connections icon, or it decides not to show any detail about it
4. There is no connection diagnostic tool as a feature
5. If it is willing to connect he thinks about it for 5min, then drops, then if he feels generous, it connects to my wifi.

How can I improve the wifi manager or find an alternative?

I saw similar questions(on alternative managers) but I'm pointing out this 5 specific problems and I'm quite ignorant about this os and would appreciate your opinion.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 05 Nov 2017 18:48 CET +0100

Booted last: 05 Nov 2017 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:80c4]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b509 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wl                   6447104  0
cfg80211              602112  1 wl
snd_soc_rt298          36864  0
snd_soc_rt286          36864  0
snd_soc_rl6347a        16384  2 snd_soc_rt298,snd_soc_rt286
snd_soc_core          233472  3 snd_soc_ssm4567,snd_soc_rt298,snd_soc_rt286
snd_pcm               102400  8 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_soc_rt298,snd_soc_rt286,snd_soc_core
wmi                    16384  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10213 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10213 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:818475 (818.4 KB)  TX bytes:818475 (818.4 KB)

wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF2]>  
          inet addr:10.205.67.147  Bcast:10.205.71.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d3fc:b171:d58c:2ac3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:246835 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:106985
          TX packets:192322 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:352872966 (352.8 MB)  TX bytes:15634834 (15.6 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654' [AC1]>   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.205.64.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0
10.205.64.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp4s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search fastwebnet.it

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       898     1  0 14:01 ?        00:00:09 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         wl
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:04:00.0/net/wlp4s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp4s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       07747626-b1ae-43c9-879a-b5bf9b54ee72
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/36
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     54 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{3,1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   2bfa3891-ffa4-44b2-b8f7-aff32924fde0 | BOREPACLA_extCASA
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   07747626-b1ae-43c9-879a-b5bf9b54ee72 | FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.205.67.147/21
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.205.64.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             62.101.93.101
IP4.DNS[2]:                             83.103.25.250
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          fastwebnet.it
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 10.205.67.144
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       expiry = 1509905800
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       routers = 10.205.64.1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 10.205.67.147
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = fastwebnet.it
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 900
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       broadcast_address = 10.205.71.255
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 62.101.93.101 83.103.25.250
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 1350
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.248.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       network_number = 10.205.64.0
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 10.205.67.144
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::d3fc:b171:d58c:2ac3/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID                    BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY     ACTIVE  * 
WOW FI - FASTWEB        <MAC 'WOW FI - FASTWEB' [AC5]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 802.1X  no        
FASTWEB-6LYMJL          <MAC 'FASTWEB-6LYMJL' [AC3]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  69      ▂▄▆_  WPA2         no        
FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654  <MAC 'FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654' [AC1]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  54 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA1         yes     * 
BOREPACLA_extCASA       <MAC 'BOREPACLA_extCASA' [AC4]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2    no        
TIM-51262209            <MAC 'TIM-51262209' [AN5]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2    no        
FILDEX                  <MAC 'FILDEX' [AC6]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2    no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CattoniHotel]] (600 root)
[connection] id=CattoniHotel | type=wifi | permissions=user:pietro:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=CattoniHotel
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BOREPACLA_extCASA]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BOREPACLA_extCASA | type=wifi | permissions=user:pietro:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BOREPACLA_extCASA
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654]] (600 root)
[connection] id=FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BOREPACLA]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BOREPACLA | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BOREPACLA
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Rome (based on set time zone)

country DE: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS
    (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp2s0    no frequency information.

wlp4s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 34 : 5.17 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
      3   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlp4s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654' [AC1]>
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654' [AC2]>
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FASTWEB-1-001CA2C79654"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'FASTWEB-6LYMJL' [AC3]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FASTWEB-6LYMJL"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'BOREPACLA_extCASA' [AC4]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"BOREPACLA_extCASA"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'WOW FI - FASTWEB' [AC5]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"WOW FI - FASTWEB"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'FILDEX' [AC6]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FILDEX"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     E179A1F6EAA13B7BC9AF7C6
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       4.10.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D77C8F93375950F3BA95B16
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   26.192498] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[   26.196499] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   26.409275] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[   26.409323] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   39.964486] CPU: 3 PID: 453 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: P           OE   4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[   39.964566]  wl_notify_roaming_status+0xc5/0x140 [wl]
[   39.964608]  wl_event_handler+0x60/0x1e0 [wl]
[   39.964654]  ? wl_notify_scan_status+0x330/0x330 [wl]
[   44.440574] CPU: 3 PID: 453 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: P        W  OE   4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[   44.440695]  wl_notify_roaming_status+0xc5/0x140 [wl]
[   44.440775]  wl_event_handler+0x60/0x1e0 [wl]
[   44.440873]  ? wl_notify_scan_status+0x330/0x330 [wl]
[ 1103.926156] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[ 1103.928100] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[ 1104.111036] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 1104.111107] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[17200.571909] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : 

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: If you state that you saw similar question please provide links to them. Please try to remove some clutter from your question and make it a bit more readable and understandable

Comment: I doubt that it is your wifi manager, usually known as Network Manager. I suspect your wireless driver and its interaction with settings in your router. Please provide the diagnostics here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: I took the screen of the console, if you need translation let me know. @chili555 I must tell you that I personally had to install ubuntu on an ex-windows, and I had to work a lot on the drivers.I've never done such things before.

Comment: You didn't post the wireless info. You posted a screenshot of the script output. The result is saved as a file.

Comment: ok I pasted the right text i hope

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and *certainly not TKIP*. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Comment: ok @chili555 i'll try to find out on the web how to do what you said. except for the speed thing because i can stream720/1080, so I'd rather not change a thing there

Comment: I suggest that you try both ways and test.